# I have read that primitive data types are faster than their classes, but what about autoboxing?

Tags: java

I have read that primitive data types are faster than their classes and take less memory, but what about autoboxing? They will also wrapped to the wrapper classes as an object, then what is the benefit to use primitives?

Comment: "autoboxing they will also wrapped to the wrapper classes as an object" - only when required (ex. if you are adding to a `List<Integer>`).

Comment: 'Primitive data types are faster than their classes.' This can only refer to the classes they get autoboxed into. So they are faster than their autoboxed equivalents. So what is your question?

Comment: Actually i was confused about autoboxing that whenver we write like int i=10 it will be wrapped to the wrapper class automatically but now i understand that it only happens when required and thank u for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't expect auto-boxing to be any more efficient than the round trip of `box_type.valueOf(value)` where `box_type` is the relevant type(*).

The main burden of autoboxing is creating and destroying objects. Generational Garbage Collectors are built for that scenario but can still get overwhelmed.

Indeed if values are being put in containers frequently it may be more effective to hold boxed values in situations where a primitive is sufficient (e.g. a class field) to reduce the number of autoboxing steps that take place.

That is, don't think of boxed values as slow. Think of boxing (auto or otherwise) as a small overhead that could be significant at very large volumes.

(*) It could be less efficient but that would seem unlikely on any serious platform. However there's no guarantee that `box_type.valueOf(value)` is ever more efficient than `new box_type(value)` plus eventual clean-up.

Answer (score 1):

Autoboxing doesn't happen unless it's necessary.

To make your rule complete, you should add something like **"avoid writing code that makes autoboxing necessary when that  can be avoided."**